# How to assign values to my CloudFormation template written in YAML while deploying

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation

I have written a CloudFormation template in YAML to deploy my AWS Lambda functions. I have to deploy multiple Lambda function and I want to be able to changes the key-value pair at run-time, so that I don't have to copy the entire thing again and again to make changes before deployment.

I was reading about the set builtin of Linux, but didn't find it of much help

```yaml
NameOfMyLambda:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties: 
    FunctionName:  !Sub '@My_Function_Name'
    Handler: app.lambda_handler
    Runtime: python3.7
    MemorySize: 256     
    Role: !GetAtt MyExecutionRole.Arn
    CodeUri: 'path/to/my/python/file'
```

In the above given code, I want to be able to change the "FunctionName" and "Role" at time of deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Your exact use case isn't completely clear (how are you running your cloudformation?), but it sounds like you want to use [CloudFormation Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) possibly combined with [Nested stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html)

This would allow you to reference your cloudformation template multiple times from within an outer template, passing different parameters each time.